# How to fetch records from mutilple tables based on id and display it in html page

Tags: html, mysql

I have a requirement where i need to generate summary of a patient. So i am using mysql database and the patient details is spread across mutiple tables.How to pull out the patient details from all the tables and display eg:

```
select * from tablea,tableb,tablec,tabled where fileid="12"
```

i know that above query is wrong but is there any way where we can pull out the patient details from multiple tables as i have used in the query?

Comment: "The above code works for tables having records in a single row". There is nothing in your query which would explicitly limit the results to a single row. a WHERE clause, as you suggested, would do that, assuming the column you filter on is unique. Anyway there seem to be several questions in one here...you ask about changing the SQL query, but also about putting the results into HTML (which is really too broad for this format, and you can find tutorials etc anyway by the dozen online), and also it's not clear what you actually want the results of your query to be, or what the data looks like

Comment: Try to narrow down the question to a single specific problem, and provide enough information about the situation to actually make it answerable (i.e. source data sample, query being used, actual output, desired output). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance.

Comment: Yes sir i have simplified the question, as mentioned above i want to pull the data stored across mutiple tables. Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: Did you miss my point where I said "provide enough information about the situation to actually make it answerable (i.e. source data sample, query being used, actual output, desired output)."? On a very basic level your query is bad because you aren't using JOINs (again, an online SQL tutorial will introduce the principle and the syntax to you), but other than that I can't tell you anything because you didn't provide enough information. Perhaps also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to understand how to produce a usable example of your problem.